wordpress get_users returning an extra field when using fields arg
I am trying to return the users of my wordpress site with get_users. However, when I pass an array of fields as an arg I find in my results that the ID is in the results twice. If I just send 'ID' instead of adding display-name then I only get 1 ID.
EDIT
What I want is for 1 ID and 1 display name. the provided solution below does work. I'm just curious as to why my original method has two instances of the ID when I include as an Arg.
//$args = array(
    //'fields' => array('ID','display_name')
 //); - same behavior as below
$args = array();
$args['fields'] = array('id','display_name');
$users = get_users($args);
echo json_encode($users);

results in:
[{"ID":"1","display_name":"it@hennig.ame.com","id":"1"},{"ID":"7","display_name":"John Brooks","id":"7"},{"ID":"11","display_name":"Josh Green","id":"11"},{"ID":"13","display_name":"Karyn Ross","id":"13"},{"ID":"9","display_name":"Mark Cunningham","id":"9"},{"ID":"6","display_name":"Noah Goellner","id":"6"},{"ID":"14","display_name":"Roderick Hennl","id":"14"},{"ID":"8","display_name":"Randy Olson","id":"8"},{"ID":"12","display_name":"skylar@hennig.ame.com","id":"12"},{"ID":"5","display_name":"Troy Davidson","id":"5"}]


get_users always include the user_login field by default, even if it's not specified in the fields argument.
To get only the user ID and display name, you can modify the code slightly.
$args = array();
$users = get_users($args);

$filtered_users = array();

foreach ($users as $user) {
  $filtered_users[] = array(
     'ID' => $user->ID,
     'display_name' => $user->display_name
   );
}

echo json_encode($filtered_users);

Result:
[{"ID":1,"display_name":"Gyan G"},{"ID":2,"display_name":"user 2"}]


I should have been more clear in my post. I do still want an ID along with the display_name. using my method, if I only select display name in my args then I only get the display name and no ID. it's only when I include ID in the args that they get doubled. Regardless, your code does work, so thank you for your answer
